# Преобразовать UTF-8 кодировку в windows-1251

Tags: laravel, excel

Использую пакет Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel. Сделал экспорт csv файла:

```
return (new DoorphoneExport)->download('doorphones.csv', Excel::CSV);
```

В конфиге прописал:

```
'csv'                    => [
        'delimiter'              => ',',
        'enclosure'              => '"',
        'line_ending'            => PHP_EOL,
        'use_bom'                => true,
        'include_separator_line' => false,
        'excel_compatibility'    => false,
    ],
```

Проблема в том, что создаётся csv файл в формате UTF-8. Как его изменить на windows-1251 ?

Comment: iconv -f utf-8 -t WINDOWS-1251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использование диска приведет к задержке.

Кроме того, если придет 2 одновременных запроса, они будут писать в один файл, и один из них не сможет это сделать.

Как сделать лучше: использовать потоки. Конкретно в вашем случае в документации даже показано как это сделать: [php.net](https://php.net/manual/ru/filters.convert.php#filters.convert.iconv) - в этом примере пишется в `php://output`. Чтобы отдавать в виде `response`, нужно писать в `php://memory`, получится так:

```
<?php

// пример текста
$text = "текст в кодировке utf-8";

$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
stream_filter_append($fp, 'convert.iconv.utf-8.cp1251', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE);

/**
 * замените эту часть на (new DoorphoneExport)->store($fp);
 */
fwrite($fp, $text);

rewind($fp);
$data = stream_get_contents($fp);

/**
 * замените эту часть на return response($data);
 */
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение: сохранил в файл, изменил кодировку, отправил результат в response

```
(new DoorphoneExport)->store('doorphones.csv');
    $text = file_get_contents(storage_path('app') . '/doorphones.csv');
    $csv = mb_convert_encoding($text, "windows-1251", "utf-8");

    return response($csv);
```